# Click counter via Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
Table: links

id     link_ref             name          clicks   unique_clicks       url
1    external_link      EXTERNAL LINK        2         1            .index.php    


Table:links_clicks

id   link_id     ip     date    hour
1       2      an_ip  a_date  a_hour
```

These are the tables and below is the code I have tried:

```
$querym = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `links` RIGHT JOIN `links_clicks` ON `links`.`id`=`links_clicks`.`link_id`");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($querym))
{
Echo $row['link_ref']."<br>";
}
```

What I want is to display an output with all the links from "links" table and how many clicks have been made on each of them in the last 24 hours.

In table "links_clicks" are stored all the clicks and in "links" are stored the informations about each external link.

links.id is the same with many link_clicks.link_id

So,

1. How do I join tables it's the first question.
2. Related to the 1: How do i count the clicks for each link?
3. How do i count the clicks on a link in a period of time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, use a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` column in your `links_clicks` table rather than separated `DATE` and `INT` columns to hold date and hour.

Second, go read up on JOIN operations. It's not clear to my why you're using a right outer join. An inner join will work fine.

Third, pro-tip: Don't use `SELECT *` in software. It usually returns too much information.

Fourth, you need some aggregate query capability (`GROUP BY`).

Try this query to get a listing of links that were clicked in the most recent 24 hours and the number of times they were clicked, ordered by most-clicked first.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num,
       links.url
  FROM links
  JOIN links_clicks ON links.id = links_clicks.link_id
 WHERE links_clicks.click_timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
 GROUP BY links.url
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

If a pure row count is not what you need, you can use something besides `COUNT(*)` for the aggregate query.  For example, you could try

```
 COUNT(distinct links_clicks.ip)
```

if you only want to count each distinct `ip` value once.

Comment: I learned new things.Thnak you ! (I know it's against the rules but I had to do it.) Edit: It's possible to ignore duplicate values for links_clicks.ip ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) AS total_click FROM links_clicks WHERE link_id = ?;
```

Should get you started, do that for each link.

Or you could be more complex and do

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT c.link_id) FROM link_clicks c LEFT JOIN links l ON (c.link_id=l.link_id) GROUP BY l.link_ref
```

These get you started, you can narrow the results down with date ranges etc.